# Building a custom timeline

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, algorithm, timeline

I am looking for creating a total custom timeline,

Like what i am really looking for is how to display the dates and handle whenever the scrolling happens over them.

The handling of dates happens in php, or javascript can handle it.

Looking for the guidance.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I am looking to build this in html5 canvas.
that is the region i have to start from scratch.

Comment: Do you have any code to use as a reference in order to see what you want? Or maybe what you want the result to be? :)